# Create labels or annotation from two color images

Tags: deep-learning, labels, annotation

I have two categories of images to use in my deep learning model. The firs category is aerial images that contain roads (such as road-1.jpg). The second category is two color images that contains road and non-road areas (such as annotation-1.jpg ). I want use second category for labels. So how can I create labels or annotation from second category images.I know there are some image cutting tools. But I'm looking for a tool that does this automatically by using the color information in the images. For example, I want to automatically create label map for the red areas in annotation-1.jpg.   In addition, I am going to use the Python programming language and the Tensorflow library.

[image: road-1.jpg]
[image: annotation-1.jpg]

Comment: I'm not sure I can understand the question the way it is asked now.

Comment: Dear @Dr. H. Lecter, I have added some details.